# Set image always in center canvas after rotation (Windows phone 8)

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any way to set image always center canvas in windows phone 8 application.
In my app, i have image inside canvas. Here is xaml code

```
       <Canvas Name="myCanvas" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
          <Image Canvas.ZIndex="1" Name="OrginalImage"

        </Image>
```

in code behind

```
 private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait) == (PageOrientation.Portrait))
        {
            OrginalImage.Width = _screeenWidth - 50;
            OrginalImage.Height = double.NaN;
            //Canvas.SetTop(OrginalImage, _screenHeight / 2 - OrginalImage.Width / 2);
            //Canvas.SetLeft(OrginalImage, _screeenWidth/2 - OrginalImage.ActualHeight/2);
        }
        // If not in portrait, move buttonList content to visible row and column.
        else
        {
            OrginalImage.Height = _screeenWidth - 100;
            OrginalImage.Width = double.NaN;
            //Canvas.SetTop(OrginalImage, _screeenWidth / 2 - OrginalImage.ActualWidth / 2);
            //Canvas.SetLeft(OrginalImage, _screenHeight/2 - OrginalImage.Height/2);

        }
    }
```

My ideas is when OrientationChanged, i set image width and height after that i put it in center. But this code doesn't set image in center of canvas?

Answer (score 0):

In general you should avoid using `Canvas` unless you have a very specific reason for doing so (eg, maybe a drawing program or a game). Instead, prefer to use something like a `Grid` that lets you use relative positioning:

```
<Grid>
  <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes Peter, my app is drawing program

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a solution to resize image. This is my code. Hope this help someone like me

```
  void ResizeImage(bool center)
    {
        if (_coercedScale != 0 && _bitmap != null)
        {
            double newWidth = myCanvas.Width = Math.Round(_bitmap.PixelWidth * _coercedScale);
            double newHeight = myCanvas.Height = Math.Round(_bitmap.PixelHeight * _coercedScale);

            xform.ScaleX = xform.ScaleY = _coercedScale;

            viewport.Bounds = new Rect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

            if (center)
            {
                viewport.SetViewportOrigin(
                    new Point(
                        Math.Round((newWidth - viewport.ActualWidth) / 2),
                        Math.Round((newHeight - viewport.ActualHeight) / 2)
                        ));
            }
            else
            {
                Point newImgMid = new Point(newWidth * _relativeMidpoint.X, newHeight * _relativeMidpoint.Y);
                Point origin = new Point(newImgMid.X - _screenMidpoint.X, newImgMid.Y - _screenMidpoint.Y);
                viewport.SetViewportOrigin(origin);
            }
        }
    }
```